# Laravel - whereDate() not giving expected result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this code in Laravel-5.8:

Controller:

```
$currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
$currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')
                 ->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
                 ->whereDate('resumption_date', '<=', $currentDate)
                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO `hr_leave_requests` (`id`, `employee_id`, `commencement_date`, `resumption_date`, `leave_status`,`created_at`) VALUES
(4, 470,'2021-03-15', '2021-03-25', 4,'2021-03-16 16:23:40');
```

This is not giving me the expected result because `resumption_date` is greater than `$currentDate`.

How do I get this resolved:

Thanks

Comment: Please share your `resumption_date` format and some value sample

Comment: @A.ANoman - I have update my code with sample data in the code. I've also shared it here:  INSERT INTO `hr_leave_requests` (`id`, `employee_id`, `commencement_date`, `resumption_date`, `leave_status`,`created_at`) VALUES
(4, 470,'2021-03-15', '2021-03-25', 4,'2021-03-16 16:23:40');

Comment: `2021-03-25` >= `2021-03-21` this is truth. So your condition is false. Now question what is your expected result?

Comment: Or more to the point, what result *are* you getting?

Comment: @A.ANoman - If the condition is true, I am selecting leave_status. The condition is false yet it selects it

Comment: @miken32 - From my post, using $currentstatus.  If the condition is true, I am selecting leave_status. The condition is false yet it selects it

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used a normal `where`, so in your case:

```
$currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')
    ->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
    ->where('resumption_date', '<=', $currentDate)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->first();
```

I suspect this method doesn't work well with Carbon instances, nowhere in the Laravel docs does it show you it being used with anything other than a string.

Comment: There is no "Carbon instance" involved here.

Comment: @miken32 - Carbon is invoked here: $currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');   Check the question. Or what else do I need to do

Comment: That's a string.

Comment: Correct - apologies I didn't see it was being passed as a string,